# Is there a term for the idea that mathematical objects are defined by their relationships?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, definition, philosophy

In a recent Veritasium video discussing Euclid's Elements, Alex Kontorovich comments that Euclid's definitions of primitive objects (e.g. "A point is that which has no part.") are absurd and lead to an infinite regression of definitions. He goes on to say:

> You shouldn't have definitions; you should have undefined terms...
> It's the relationships between the objects that's important, not the definitions of the objects themselves.

(timestamped link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFlu60qs7_4&t=1042s

Is there an agreed-upon term for the idea that a mathematical object is entirely defined by its relationships to other mathematical objects? I'd like to read more about it, but I don't know what to search for.

Comment: That's exactly what happens in the axiomatic method... of which is what Euclid was the first practitioner. I haven't seen that video, but to me it sounds like Kontorovich is overinterpreting that passage.

Comment: Structuralism is the best fit as mentioned in the answer.  A similar concept in applied fields you may find interesting is systems thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the philosophy of mathematics, the term is *structuralism*. See [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/) for a survey.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to [extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensionality) (but not identical).